# Why does subprocess.Popen("ssh... ", preexec_fn=os.setpgrp) stop/hang when I press return?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, subprocess

I'm observing the following script hang under a particular scenario described below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess as sp
import time

tres = 0.1
time.sleep(2)

user_at_host = "user@host"

child_proc = sp.Popen(["ssh", "-q", user_at_host, "ls"], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)

while(child_proc.poll() is None):
    time.sleep(tres)
```

When I run the script with a valid "user@host", I normally just get the output from "ls", but if I push the Enter/Return key before the "sleep(2)" ends, it hangs (with no output) when we get to the "ls" sub-process and I have to interrupt it.

```
ps aux | grep ls
user  14216  0.0  0.0   6844  2856 pts/27   T    18:18   0:00 ssh -q user@host ls
```

As you can see it's in the "stopped" state.

If I don't use "preexec_fn=os.setpgrp", there is no hang.

Also, if I replace the remote ssh/ls call with a local ls call, there is no hang.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

EDIT:
Authentication of ssh is performed via public key.
There is no output when the process hangs/stops. 
I'm using python 2.4.3, but have observed the problem in 2.6.6 as well.

Comment: how do you authenticate to remote host? How do you run the script? What is the terminal output?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the requested info.

Comment: The script is run in a bash shell by just typing the relative path at the prompt "./scriptname.py"

Comment: You should be able to replicate my observation by copying the script exactly into a text file, and replacing "user@host" with something valid for yourself, including "<user>@localhost" or just "localhost"

Comment: Why exactly do you need `setpgrp`?

Comment: This is a very stripped down example program. In the real program, I'm catching signals.  In order to prevent the keyboard interrupt signal from being sent to a child process, I'm putting the children in their own process group.